# If I could not iterate through Match.object, what should I do instead?

Tags: python, outlook, match

I am struggling with one function. It is a function for **scraping** outlook, it finds a particular word "Number1" and selects numbers that are near this word. Some of these numbers begin with "0" and I want to change it to "32" instead of "0" and save as a list.

But I could not iterate through Match.object and I do not know any other possibilities how to achieve my goal.

This is what I have tried:

```
def get_number(file):
   try:
       body = file.body
       matches = re.finditer(r"Number1:\s(.*)$", body, re.MULTILINE)
       list_of_numbers = []
       for match in matches:
             for i in match.group(1):
                  if i[0] == 0:
                      list_of_numbers.append("32" + i[1:])
        return list_of_numbers
      

   except Exception as e:
       print(e)
```

This is an example of typical email:

```
Subject: Test1

Hi,
You got a new answer from user Alex. 

Code: alex123fj
Number1: 0611111111
Number2: 1020
Number3: 3032
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex will find only `Number1: ..` but there might be multiple numbers that starts with 0 as you stated in your question. Here is the way to get the desired output:

```
import re

body = """
Subject: Test1

Hi,
You got a new answer from user Alex. 

Code: alex123fj
Number1: 0611111111
Number2: 1020
Number3: 3032
"""

matches = re.findall(r"^Number.*$", body, re.MULTILINE)
# -> [Number1: 0611111111, Number2: 1020, Number3: 3032]

# getting only numbers from that list
nums = [ch for match in matches for ch in match.split() if ch.isdigit()]
# -> ['0611111111', '1020', '3032']

list_of_numbers = ['32' + i[1:] for i in nums if i[0] == '0']
# -> ['32611111111']
```